# Find colorindex from palette for coloring rows when value changes VBA

Tags: vba, excel, color-palette

Code:

```
Public Sub HighLightRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 2       'Color 1

    'Dim colorIndex As XlColorIndex: colorIndex = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(10)
    'MsgBox colorIndex

    Do While (Cells(i, 1) <> "")
        If (Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1)) Then 'check for different value in cell A (index=1)
            If c = 2 Then
                c = 24   'color 2
            Else
                c = 2   'color 1
            End If
        End If

        Rows(Trim(Str(i)) + ":" + Trim(Str(i))).Interior.colorIndex = c
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

This code works perfectly and changes color when value in the column changes. But the colors are specified in the code. I want the user to select color of his/her choice.

Output that I am getting with above code:
[image]

**What I want the code to do:**
Open the color palette.
User selects a color.
Color index is passed to a variable.
When value changes, rows is colored alternatively with white & the color selected.

Eg. if user selects blue from palette, the rows will be blue & white with alternate groups.if user selects green from palette, the rows will be green & white with alternate groups.
I tried including this code :

```
Dim colorIndex As XlColorIndex: colorIndex = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(10)
MsgBox colorIndex
```

palette opens up perfectly, but `MsgBox colorIndex` gives me -1 as output.

I cant seem to get this to work. Any change in code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor)` returns `True = -1` if a color was selected and `False = 0` if the user pressed cancel. To get the selected color use `ActiveWorkbook.Colors(10)` like in the example below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorPaletteDialogBox()
    Dim lcolor As Long
    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(10) = True Then
      'user pressed OK
      lcolor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(10)
      ActiveCell.Interior.Color = lcolor
    Else
      'user pressed Cancel
    End If
End Sub
```

---

So for your loop you could use something like …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HighLightRows()
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 2       'Color 1

    Dim i As Long 'integer is too small for row counting!
    i = 2

    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(10) = True Then
        Do While (Cells(i, 1) <> "")
            If (Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1)) Then 'check for different value in cell A (index=1)
                If c = 2 Then
                    c = 10   'color 2
                Else
                    c = 2   'color 1
                End If
            End If

            Rows(Trim(Str(i)) + ":" + Trim(Str(i))).Interior.colorIndex = c
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Else
      'user pressed Cancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you guide me how to implement your answer in my code? I changed c=24 to c=ActiveWorkbook.Colors(10). For this I am getting Overflow error.

Comment: @AmanDevrath see my edit. The color index where the selected color is, is 10. If you use `Show(10)` then use `colorIndex = 10`.

Comment: I just had to change 1 line. Perfect. Thankyou so much. One question though, when the code colors the rows, the column lines goes away. is it possible that lines don't become invisible ?

Comment: @AmanDevrath no, grid lines are only visible if there is no color otherwise you need to draw your own borders (but this is another question). If this answer solved your issue please mark it as solution.

Comment: Okay. I'm fine with this. Thank you for your efforts. :)